# Using MIN() instead of top 1 for an SQL query

Tags: sql-server

**WORKS**

```
employeeName    companyName     salary
John            Samsung         10000
Paul            Apple           15000
Petr            Samsung          7500
```

Consider the table 'Works' given above. I want to "Find the company with the smallest payroll (total wages of employees)", which is in this case Apple. I have achieved the required output using this query:

`select top 1 SUM(salary) as sal, companyName from Works group by companyName order by sal`

However, I would like to have a query with MIN() function instead of top function as its allowed in sql server but not in all dbms. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `MIN` alone won't achieve this. I'm not really sure I understand your aversion to `TOP`. When writing SQL you write it per the RDBMS you are using; in this case T-SQL. Although there is ISO standards for SQL, none of the RDBMS completely adhere to it and the parts they do are not shared between each. If you're using T-SQ:, why not make use of the tool(s) you have? If you do have to switch RDBMS, then you're going to need to rewrite a lot of your SQL anyway.

Comment: why apple why not samsung?

Comment: @Larnu mainly I'm curious about doing this query without TOP

Comment: @PSK apple's payroll = 15k & samsung's payroll = 17.5k in above example so apple has the smallest payroll

Comment: Oh, it's the TOTAL payroll. *This is why expected results and details in the question (not the comments) are **important**.*

Comment: Your dream is generally unrealistic. SQL dialects and functionality differ so greatly between dbms engines, forcing designers and developers to write code specific to one engine. Trying to limit a system to using that subset of sql and features common to some set of engines is difficult at best. And if you have no specific engines you wish to target, then this will become impossible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to use `TOP` then you could use a CTE with `MIN`. Of course, if you have multiple rows with the same minimum values all of them will be returned:

```
WITH VTE AS(
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES('J','S',10000),
                ('P','A',15000),
                ('S','S',7500))V(Emp, Comp, Sal)),
CTE AS(
    SELECT Comp,
           Sal,
           MIN(Sal) OVER () AS MinSal
    FROM VTE)
SELECT Comp,
       Sal
FROM CTE
WHERE Sal = MinSal;
```

Edit, based on the *new* information in the comments... (*"apple's payroll = 15k & samsung's payroll = 17.5k in above example so apple has the smallest payroll"*) this should get the result the OP is after. I still think `TOP` would be far more succinct here though.

```
WITH VTE AS(
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES('J','S',10000),
                ('P','A',15000),
                ('S','S',7500))V(Emp, Comp, Sal)),
Tots AS(
    SELECT Comp,
           SUM(sal) AS TotSal
    FROM VTE
    GROUP BY Comp),
CTE AS (
    SELECT Comp,
           TotSal,
           MIN(TotSal) OVER () AS MinTotSal
    FROM Tots)
SELECT Comp,
       TotSal
FROM CTE
WHERE TotSal = MinTotSal;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the result rows of the below is the same as what you got with using TOP 1. 
But, this is not nice. The reason is why the cost of execution is very expensive.

```
DECLARE salary_cursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT companyName, MIN(sal) as sal
FROM (
    SELECT SUM(salary) AS sal, companyName FROM Works group by companyName 
    ) T
GROUP BY companyName; 

OPEN salary_cursor; 

FETCH NEXT FROM salary_cursor; 


CLOSE salary_cursor;  
DEALLOCATE salary_cursor;
```

Comment: A Cursor? This will be really slow with a large dataset, and even with a small one a set based approach will out perform it hands down. I really don't recommend this.

Comment: @Larnu I'm agree with you. but, CTE is not quite cheap operation.

Comment: A CTE can be a very cheap operation. In terms of what we have here, this would certainly be one of those cases.

Comment: I'm not sure that. If you need to save the execution time, I really recommand that you remove the VALUES phrase. the IO operation is most expensive than the others.

Comment: Huh? `VALUES` is the sample data in that query... And `VALUES` is far from expensive in that query, it won't cause any IO.

Comment: Good opinion! I just said what I know all.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, then you want to get the max average salary. If it is true, then try to use the following code:

```
DECLARE @table TABLE
(
    employeeName VARCHAR(50),
    companyName VARCHAR(50),
    salary INT
)

INSERT INTO @table
(
    employeeName,
    companyName,
    salary
)
VALUES
('John','Samsung',10000),
('Paul','Apple',15000),
('Petr','Samsung',7500)

;WITH cte AS (
SELECT 
  tbl.companyName
, AVG(tbl.salary) AvgSalary
FROM @table tbl
GROUP BY tbl.companyName
)
SELECT 
  q.companyName
, q.AvgSalary
FROM 
cte q
WHERE  q.AvgSalary IN (SELECT MAX(cte.AvgSalary) FROM cte )
```

OUTPUT:

```
companyName   AvgSalary
Apple            15000
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple example. It's not perfect, and can lead to issues where duplicates occur.

```
  SELECT * FROM (
                SELECT SUM(w.salary) sumSalary, w.cpyname FROM @work AS w
                GROUP BY w.cpyname) g
GROUP BY sumSalary, g.cpyname
HAVING g.sumSalary =  (
SELECT MIN(f.sumSalary)  FROM (
SELECT SUM(w.salary) sumSalary, w.cpyname FROM @work AS w
GROUP BY w.cpyname)f )
```

*EDIT*
I missed the bit where OP was summing by companyname

Answer (score 0):

**Query to prepare dummy data:**

```
declare @Works TABLE 
(
  EmployeeName varchar(100),
  CompanyName varchar(100),
  Salary int  
)

Insert into @Works Select 'John', 'Samsung', 10000
Insert into @Works Select 'Paul', 'Apple', 15000
Insert into @Works Select 'Petr', 'Samsung', 7500
;
```

**Actual Query:**

```
WITH CTE AS 
(SELECT CompanyName, SUM(Salary) as TotalSalary FROM @Works GROUP BY CompanyName)
SELECT CompanyName, TotalSalary FROM CTE WHERE TotalSalary = 
(SELECT MIN(TotalSalary) FROM CTE)
```

**Output**

[image]